# How can we formalize this procedure of converting first order logic formulas into propsitional formulas?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Here is a procedure which shows us how to convert any FOL formula into a propositional formula:

[image]

I wonder how to formalize this rigurously in a simple way? by that I mean, give a precise definition which shouws a machine how to construct $\phi_p$ from $\phi$.

I tried doing this but I didn't find a simple rigurous formalization for this untill now (I have a very complicated formlization which may take about 1.5-2 page though! but this works only for countable languages)

Any good(simple) formalization?

Comment: You have to parse the *formation tree*, in order to intercept the *scope* of quantifiers. The rule is that the "atoms" to be replaced by propositional letters must not be in the scope of quantifiers. Thus, a formula like $(x=y) \rightarrow \forall z(P(z,x) \rightarrow P(z,y))$ must be transalted as $p_1 \rightarrow p_2$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I understand that. I meant to define such procedure recursively, this may make my question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

See Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122384520) (2nd ed - 2001), page 114 for the "specification" of the process (it does not mean that it is easily translatable into a computer program ...) :

> Divide the wffs into two groups:
>
> > 1. The *prime* formulas are the atomic formulas and those of the form $∀x \alpha$ [for Enderton, only $\forall$ is primitive; $\exists$ is an abbreviation for $\lnot \forall \lnot$].
> > 2. The nonprime formulas are the others, i.e., those of the form $¬ \alpha$ or $\alpha → \beta$ [again : $\lor, \land$ and $\leftrightarrow$ are abbreviations].
>
> Thus any formula is built up from prime formulas by the operations $\mathcal E_¬$ and $\mathcal E_→$ [see page 17 for the *formula-building operations*].
>
> Now go back to sentential logic, but take the sentence symbols to be the prime formulas of our first-order language.

---

The "procedure" must start from formula $\varphi$ and decompose it according to the main connective; if there is none, i.e. if the formula is $\forall x \psi$, then it is a *prime* and thus we are done: its "propositional transformation" is simply $p_1$.

If the main connective is $\rightarrow$, this means that $\varphi$ is $\psi_1 \rightarrow \psi_2$. Then we have to "search into" the two sub-formulae for their main connectives, if any; otherwise they are *prime*.